# Nginx docker container returning corrupt JSON file, renamed file

Tags: json, nginx, docker

I have a JSON file that nginx serves directly as a static file. For some reason the json file served by a specific URL has become corrupted to the point that viewing it in both Chrome/cURL causes weird behaviour such as out of order output, " characters", etc.

If I rename the static file, it is output perfectly fine.

The server is a docker container and the error is surviving container restarts (`docker rm/run`) and even rebuilds of the image (`docker build`), so I'm wondering if this issue is some how related to boot2docker or is there opportunity for containers/images to retain some sort of cache?

EDIT:

Looks like this issue was found before https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/705

Would docker-machine also likely inherit this issue?

Comment: Are you mounting a volume from host? Or are you using a data container?

Comment: Both in fact, the volume is Shared by Virtualbox to a data container which is then shared with `--volumes-from` to multiple other containers

Comment: Strange, a data container is not supposed to mount a volume from the host. Could you try it with an empty data volume container? (one one build from an image where you COPY what you need and then `docker create` it?)

Comment: Yes, docker machine uses boot2docker under the hood, see https://docs.docker.com/machine/#understand-docker-machine-basic-concepts . At least as long as you are on the virtual box.

Comment: Are you on Windows? I'm having the same issue. Unmounting the file should work.. Also docker down en up ("have you turning it off and on again") works for me.  Docker v 1.12

Comment: I was on OSX / Boot2Docker when I was getting this issue, I don't recall that stop/start fixed it, but it has been a long time. I've not seen the issue at all since migrating to Docker For Mac though (away from docker-machine)